# get problem my stellar is lock

Tags: transactions, error

i get the problem cannot withdraw with my account after get this issue.
i dont know to fix this problem please help me thx.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you set the weight of the account master key to 0, it is no longer able to authorize any operations.  As you pointed out, the thresholds for operations are set to 1 on that account. So unfortunately, unless there are other signers on the account, you are no longer able to do anything with that account, including make a payment.

For more info, check out the Multisignature docs:

https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/multisig/#additional-signing-keys